# Refresh Power Queries Then Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to update about a dozen Power Queries, wait until those are completed, and then refresh all the Pivot Tables attached to them.

I have this VBA Script, I have put notes around the section that I am struggling with:

```
Public Sub UpdatePowerQueries()

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Unprotect
Next Worksheet

'Start of trouble section
Dim StatusCheck As Long, Connection As WorkbookConnection, RefreshCheck As String, RefreshCheckLoop As Integer

On Error Resume Next
For Each Connection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    StatusCheck = InStr(1, Connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection, "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1", vbTextCompare)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Exit For
    End If
If StatusCheck > 0 Then Connection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
If StatusCheck > 0 Then Connection.Refresh

RefreshCheckLoop = 1

While RefreshCheckLoop < 15
    RefreshCheck = Connection.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
    If RefreshCheck = True Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    RefreshCheckLoop = RefreshCheckLoop + 1
Wend
Next Connection

DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
'End of trouble section

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Visible Then
        Worksheet.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    End If
Next Worksheet
    
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Protect
Next Worksheet

Worksheets("Table Of Contents").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Everywhere I read, it says to set the BackgroundQuery to false and it should wait until that finishes before moving onto the next section of refreshing the pivot tables, but I am still getting the annoying little yellow triangle telling me that the "Download did not complete." next to each query. I have all the Power Queries set to not update via the "RefreshAll" command.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would suggest to check if it is still Refreshing before moving to the next one.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oledbconnection.refreshing  and then DoEvents

Comment: On the first error in the loop you break out of the loop - what about the other connections after the one with the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams, they all error...even though the data appears to refresh.

Comment: @Sorceri, I have updated the logic above. I have added a loop to see if the connection is still refreshing and then a DoEvents after the Power Query refresh and before the RefreshAll. I am still having the same yellow triange.

Comment: What I mean is that as soon as one connection errors within your `For Each Connection In ThisWorkbook.Connections` loop, you exit the loop.  Unless there's only one connection per workbook?

Comment: @TimWilliams, all the data appears to be refreshing and I can refresh manually, so it doesn't appear to be erroring other than the fact I get the yellow triange. Is there something in my logic that you would suggest that I change to make it more efficient or so that it doesn't break the loop? Sorry, I am still very much learning VBA scripting.

Comment: @TimWilliams, even when I comment out the "If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear Exit For End If" logic, it still gives me the yellow triange.

Comment: OK - that was my only observation: I don't really use Power Query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236373/discussion-between-femmer-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Sorceri's advice. I went and added Do Events to pretty much every step of the code:

```
Public Sub UpdatePowerQueries()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Unprotect
Next Worksheet

Dim StatusCheck As Long, Connection As WorkbookConnection, RefreshCheck As String, RefreshCheckLoop As Integer

On Error Resume Next
For Each Connection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    StatusCheck = InStr(1, Connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection, "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1", vbTextCompare)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Exit For
    End If
If StatusCheck > 0 Then Connection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
If StatusCheck > 0 Then Connection.OLEDBConnection.MaintainConnection = False
If StatusCheck > 0 Then Connection.Refresh

RefreshCheckLoop = 1

While RefreshCheckLoop < 15
    RefreshCheck = Connection.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
    If RefreshCheck = True Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    RefreshCheckLoop = RefreshCheckLoop + 1
Wend
Next Connection

DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

DoEvents

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Visible Then
        Worksheet.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    End If
Next Worksheet
    
DoEvents

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Protect
Next Worksheet

DoEvents

Worksheets("Table Of Contents").Activate

DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

This appears to work as I have ran it about 10 times and not recieved my annoying yellow triange.